# Prove that for any integer value of D, the equation 27x + 14y = D has integer solutions for x and y.

Tags: diophantine-equations

Prove that for any integer value of $D$, the equation $27x + 14y = D$ has integer solutions for $x$ and $y$.

Comment: How about the special case where $D=1$?

Comment: Can I write assume D=1?

Comment: "
Can I write assume D=1"  No.  But you can *find* values of $x,y$ where $27x + 14y = 1$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown: what's so special about $D=1$ ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust: Follows from Euclidean algorithm since $\gcd(27,14)=1$.

Comment: @YadatiKiran: I know but how can the OP know ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust: That's true. The tags don't seem to suggest anything with regard to elementary number theory.

Comment: But if the OP can solve $27x + 14y = 1$ then the OP might, if clever enough, be able to apply it to solve $27x + 14y = D$.  Don't think Lord shark the Unknown is required to spell it out.  I think the OP can be expected to think it through.

Comment: I'll try my best to figure out why everyone here is loving 1 so much, thanks for helping

Comment: It might actually be worth noting and it might make it easier to notice that not only doe $27x + 14y = D$ have *one* solution.  It actually has *infinitely many solutions.  It might be barking up a wrong tree to worry about *what* the solution is for a specific solution.

Comment: Well, I love one because $1 + 1 =2$ and $2 + 1 = 3$ and $3 + 1 = 4$.  And $513*1 = 513$.  $1$ is a pretty danged wonderful number cause it gets you places.

Comment: Okay, so a kind soul here tagged diophantine equations that led me to whole new theorem which says if gcd(a,b) = c and if c divides D then equation has many integer solutions

Comment: gcd(27,14) = 1 and any number is divisible by 1 therefore any value of D is has integer solutions, thanks y'all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$27x+14y=D(28-27)$$

$\iff27(x+D)=14(2D-y)$

$\dfrac{14(2D-y)}{27}=x+D$ which is an integer

$\implies27|14(2D-y)\implies27|(2D-y)$ as $(14,27)=1$

$\dfrac{2D-y}{27}=c$(say) where $c$ is an arbitrary integer

$\implies y=?$

$\implies x=?$

Comment: I get what you are trying to say thanks but why we are trying to make it = 1?

Comment: @Yolo, I have not chosen $D=1,D$ can be any integer

Comment: Homework solution, nothing more.

Answer (score 9):

If you can find $27x_0 + 14y_0 = 1$ then can find $27(D*x_0) + 14(D*y_0) = D$.

Comment: Homework solution, nothing more.

Answer (score 5):

I'm by no means a math expert, but it seems to me that if you can solve for D=1, (x = -1, y = 2), then multiplying the entire equation by any integer, results in an integer solution for the general equation.  I don't know how to put this into mathematical proof terms, but basically because there is a solution where D = 1, then multiplying the entire equation by some arbitrary integer c means that for any integer D, there is a solution, because you can multiply both x and y by the same number, and get a solution.

Maybe someone else can give a more formal explanation of what I'm trying to say.

Comment: " then multiplying the entire equation by any integer, results in an integer solution for the general equation. " BINGO!

Answer (score 3):

$$27x + 14y = D$$

### The first step is to find one solution to $27x + 14y=1$

An "obvious" solution is $(x,y)=(-1,2)$.

Assuming you want to have a general method for finding solutions to such problems...

Start with 
\begin{array}{c} 27 = 27(1) + 14(0) \\ 14 = 27(0)+14(1) \end{array}

The idea is to manipulate "things" so that the number on the left becomes a $1$.

For example, $13 = 27 - 14 = 27(1-0) + 14(0-1)= 27(1) + 14(^-1)$.

We end up with the list

\begin{array}{rcl} 
   27 &= &27(1) + 14(0) \\ 
   14 &= &27(0)+14(1) \\
   13 &= &27(1)+14(^-1)
\end{array}

Next we see that $1=14 - 13 = 27(0-1)+14(1-(^-1))=27(^-1)+14(2)$. So the list looks like

\begin{array}{rcl} 
   27 &= &27(1) + 14(0) \\ 
   14 &= &27(0)+14(1) \\
   13 &= &27(1)+14(^-1) \\
    1 &= &27(^-1)+14(2)
\end{array}

### Next we find *a solution* to $27x + 14y=D$

Since $27(^-1)+14(2)=1$, then $27(-D)+14(2D)= D$

### Finally, we solve  $27x + 14y=D$

Suppose that $27x + 14y=D$ for some $x$ and $y$. Then 
\begin{align}
   27x + 14y=D &= 27(-D)+14(2D)= D \\
   27(x+D) &= 14(2D-y) \\
\end{align}

Since $27 \mid 27(x+D)$, then $27 \mid 14(2D-y)$.

Since $\gcd(27,14)=1$, then $27 \mid 2D-y$.

Hence, for some integer, $t$

\begin{align}
   2D - y &= 27t \\
   y &= 2D-27t
\end{align}

Next, we solve for $x$

\begin{align}
   27x + 14y &= D \\
   27x + 14(2D-27t) &= D \\
   27x + 28D - 14(27)t &= D \\
   27x &= 14(27)t - 27D \\
   x &= 14t - D
\end{align}

So the general solution is

$$(x,y) = (14t-D, 2D-27t)$$

for all integers, $t$.

Answer (score 0):

I see you have already some interesting answers and I will try another way to explain.

Let us make prime number factorization of numbers $27$ and $14$:

$$27 = 2^0\times 3^3\times 7^0\\14=2^1\times3^0\times 7^1$$

They don't have any non-zero exponent for the same prime base. This means $27$ and $14$ are *relatively prime*. If they were not relative prime, they would have some common factor $K>1$ and we could write $$K(ax+by)=D$$
But since any number $D$ is not divisible by any given common factor $K>1$, we are sure to be able to hit it.

An example if we did not have relative prime numbers is $$27x+15y=D \Leftrightarrow 3(9x+5y)=D$$
Which we can see that it could only be sure to fit if $D$ was divisible by $3$.